# N way collision of hashes

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, birthday-attack

For a collision $H(A_1) = H(A_2)$, the number of queries is $T^{1/2}$ where $\log_2(T)$ is length of hash output. Then, what would be the number of queries requried to find an $n$-collision ($H(A_1) = H(A_2) = .....  = H(A_n)$).

Comment: Is this a Merkle-Daamgard hash, or a generic hash?  For MD hashes (at least, the ones without output truncation), there are known ways to compute multiway collisions faster than expected.

Comment: Consider this as an ideal hash function. Generic.

Answer (score 5):

is $T^{1-1/n}$

---

Proof:

Suppose we have a sample set $M$, with $|M| = m$. We choose a set $N$ with $|N| = n$ among the set $M$, which is $O(m^n)$ (you know $O(m^n)=m\cdot(m-1)\cdot...\cdot(m-n+2)\cdot(m-n+1)$). In particular, we suppose $A_1, A_2, ...., A_n$ make a $n$-collision $H(A_1)=H(A_2) , H(A_2)=H(A_3) , ... , H(A_{n-1})=H(A_n)$ just as you want. Since each one of these $n-1$ events happens with probability $1/|T|$, the probability that a particular set $N$ chosen from $M$ is a $n$-collision is $O(1/|T|^{n-1}))$.Using the union bound, the probability that some set $N$ is an $n$-collision is $O(m^n/|T|^{n-1})$ and since we want this probability to be close to 1, the bound on $m$ is $T^{1-1/n}$

Comment: The answer is fine if we are content with the statement's _For a collision_ $H(A_1) = H(A_2)$, _the number of queries is_ $T^{1/2}$. $\;$ But this is less than precise; rather, the number of queries to reach an $n$-collision with odds $1/2$  (or any fixed probability in range $]0,1[$ ) is $\mathcal O(T^{1-1/n})$ when $T$ goes to infinity.

Comment: The exact work factor is worked out in [Suzuki et al](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11927587_5): $(n!)^{1/n}\cdot T^{1-1/s}$.